# Upload csv via API gateway to S3

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to set up an AWS API Gateway that could receive a POST request an upload a csv file to S3. Ideally, I would like to make some transformations to the file before uploading it to S3 (renaming and formatting some columns to normalize their names accross different uploads).

So far, I have set up my API Gateway to receive the request and send it to an AWS Lambda. I use Lambda proxy integration. The triggered lambda is as follows:

```
import logging
import pandas as pd
import boto3


logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

s3 = boto3.client("s3")

def handler(event, context):
    logger.info(f"Event: {event}")
    df = pd.read_csv(event['body']['file'])
    logger.info(f"df1: {df}")

    # Provided parameters
    try:
        code = event['body']['code']
    except KeyError:
        logger.info('Code not provided')
        code = 'Code'
    try:
        date = event['body']['date']
    except KeyError:
        logger.info('Date not provided')
        date = 'Date'
    try:
        debit = event['body']['debit']
    except KeyError:
        logger.info('Debit not provided')
        debit = 'Debit'
    try:
        credit = event['body']['credit']
    except KeyError:
        logger.info('Credit not provided')
        credit = 'Credit'
    try:
        id= event['body']['id']
    except KeyError:
        logger.info('Id not provided')
        id = '001'
    df.rename(columns={code: 'Code', date: 'Date', credit: 'Credit', debit: 'Debit'})
    df.to_csv(f's3://bucket/{id}/file.csv', line_terminator='\n', sep = ';', date_format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'text/csv',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        },
        'body': {
            'uploaded': True
        },
        'isBase64Encoded': False
    }
```

To test this API, I use the following function:

```
import requests

csv_file = open("file.csv", 'rb')

headers = {"x-api-key": "xxx", "Content-Type":"text/csv"}
url = "https://xxx.execute-api.xxx.amazonaws.com/xxx"
body = {
    "file": csv_file,
    "code": "my_code"
}
# files = {
#     "file": ("file.csv", open('file.csv', 'r'), 'text/csv')
# }

r = requests.post(url=url, headers=headers, data=body)
print(r.text)
```

The output is {"message": "Internal server error"}, and if I look in CloudWatch logs, I see that the event is encoded this way:

```
'body': 'file=%EF%BB%BFCol1%3BCol2%3BCol3%3BCol4%0D%0A&file=11%3B12%3B13%3B14%3B%0D%0A&file=21%3B22%3B23%3B24%3B...'
```

It looks like the body is encoded and passed row by row into different "file" fields. For a file with about 5000 rows I get the error `OSError: [Errno 36] File name too long` when trying to read it.
Is there another way to proceed in order to get a full dataset that I can transform into a pandas dataframe?
I have also seen suggestions with multipart/form-data, using files=files in the request or using csv library but I keep getting similar errors.
Thank you

Comment: Have you tried surrounding the `pd.read_csv` with a `try/except` and logging? That might give you a better idea of what's going wrong

Comment: If I do so I get the same error: `OSError: [Errno 36] File name too long`, it looks like the csv file content is streamed into the "file" parameter, but the API is considering it as the file name